# JSONSerialize on different json object

Tags: swift

I am trying to use `JSONSerializer` with Codeable `Struct` which makes everything with a single line of code.

However I am struggling with the following different format of json. the cart object can be in different formats.

Please see two different formats as follows. I wonder how do you handle his scenario, what is your suggestion?

```
      "cart":{
            "49eb73d7823480a01dbbeb50461cffa8":{
               "rowId":"49eb73d7823480a01dbbeb50461cffa8",
               "id":1,
               "name":"Mercimek(Lentil) Soup",
               "qty":"1",
               "price":5,
               "options":{
                  "11":{
                     "id":11,
                     "name":"Toppings",
                     "values":{
                        "25":{
                           "id":25,
                           "name":"Jalapenos",
                           "qty":1,
                           "price":3.99,
                           "subtotal":3.99
                        },
                        "26":{
                           "id":26,
                           "name":"Sweetcorn",
                           "qty":1,
                           "price":1.98,
                           "subtotal":1.98
                        }
                     },
                     "subtotal":5.98
                  }
               },
               "comment":"",
               "subtotal":10.98
            }
         }
```

The another form of cart object:

```
    "cart":{
        "bf93e0040190e2a2c89570e5152c7ce1":{
           "rowId":"bf93e0040190e2a2c89570e5152c7ce1",
           "id":27,
           "name":"Humus",
           "qty":4,
           "price":4.90,
           "options":[

           ],
           "comment":null,
           "subtotal":19.6
        }
     },
```

Comment: Major difference I see is "options" being an object in one response and array in another, and "comment "  is nullable in one and empty string in other, are these the only two diffs? This is a very poor contract drawn, is this the response of your own API or your own team API? Why cant you have options as [OptionObject] in both response? Also comment optional why different structures in the first place?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, if you also check dictionary of each cart is alphanumeric value, how JSONSerializer handles this situation? for example "bf93e0040190e2a2c89570e5152c7ce1"

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, by the way I found a great open source which returns this json object which I need to handle for iOS project. I have limited knowledge on the backend part at the moment. However, the provided web application works flawlessly.

Comment: Give me sometime, Ill check this in a while, BTW I haven't down voted your question :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, thanks a lot for looking. Just ignoring who has down voted :-) . I believe that it is reasonable question to ask.

Comment: Answered your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use properties that are dictionaries in your structs to handle the inner objects

```
struct Cart: Codable {
    let cart: [String: Row]
}

struct Row: Codable {
    let rowId: String
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let qty: String
    let price: Int
    let options: [String: Option]
    let comment: String?
    let subtotal: Double
}

struct Option: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let subtotal: Double
    let values: [String: Value]
}

struct Value: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let qty: Double
    let price: Double
    let subtotal: Double
}
```

There also seems to be properties that have different types from one cart to another and then you need to implement custom `init(from)`, this one is for `qty` in `Row` but there might be more properties that needs this solution

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    rowId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .rowId)
    id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    if let value = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .qty) {
        qty = value
    } else if let value = Int(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .qty)) {
        qty = value
    }
    // rest of properties...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing good start point. How do you handle `Option` object in the Row `init()` and also Option `init()` ?

Comment: You do `options = try container.decode([String: Option].self, forKey: .options)` basically but for every property that might have different types you have to decide which type is the right one and then use the same pattern I used for `qty` above